# Replacement for PHP's virtual function?

Tags: php, html, apache, rhel7, ssi

The web team here has created a nice system of Server-Side Includes (SSI) and HTML files that give all of our web sites the same branding.

E.g., our public-facing HTML web pages start like this (strictly, this is an SHTML snippet):

```
<!--#set var="META_TITLE" value="My Web Site Title" -->
<!--#set var="PAGE_HEADER" value="My web site header text"-->

<!--#include virtual="/companyincludes/hub-page-top.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/localincludes/header-image.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/companyincludes/hub-page-top-mid.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/localincludes/nav-left.html"-->
<!--#include virtual="/companyincludes/top-close.html"-->
```

Note the SSI directives "#set var" and "#include virtual".  (There are also SSI directives like this in the "companyinclude" files.)

Let's call this collection of characters top.html.

Thus, our public-facing PHP web pages start like this:

```
<?php
virtual("top.html");
// ...
```

Note that the PHP function include() (and require() and the _once() variations) will not interpret the SSI directives in the HTML text, as shown above.  The function virtual() does this trick.

I have been told by our Apache admin team, "when we upgrade our servers to RHEL 7, we will be switching over to PHP-FPM, so the virtual command will stop working."

Is there another way to have PHP include HTML files that are parsed for SSI directives?

(The alternative we are pursuing is to re-write these include files in PHP.)

Comment: *"Replacement for PHP's virtual function?"* - What you posted there isn't PHP, it's SHTML, totally different animal. Just use PHP's `include`, no? I've used that before, even with HTML/SHTML. Edit: Unless your host doesn't allow that, for possible security reasons.

Comment: Of course.  The first code snip is SHTML and the second code snip is PHP.  The include() function of PHP does not do the SSI interpretations as seen in the first code snip.  Maybe it is a company policy, but they are not fessing up to that if it is.

Comment: I understand and I also understand the dilemma you're set in. As I said earlier, you can try to include the SHTML/HTML files from PHP since I too was faced with the same thing you're asking. Not all servers support this but you can try to include them in your PHP as you normally would any file. You can also try an Ajax method which worked for me also using the `.load()` function, when the new server a site I worked on once didn't support what I tried before. Then when it moved once again, I had no choice but to rewrite in PHP. I'd test out a few things first using what I suggested.